Solidity Debug: Require statement reverts with no error when met, but prints error when not met
Apologies if the title is a little confusing. I'm new to programming in Solidity, and I think there's just some fundamental misunderstanding I'm having on this code, and I'm unable to fix it until I learn what is wrong with my understanding of Solidity.
For context I will provide relevant code excerpts from 4 contracts, a Helper.sol file for structures, an ERC721 contract that holds state, an ERC721 interface for this contract, and a fourth contract we can called "Query.sol" which uses a combination of the previous three.
Helper.sol
pragma solidity =0.8.20;

library Helper {
    struct TreaninProps {
        bool summoned;
        uint strength;
        Faction faction;
        uint mintTime;
        bool isFrozen;
        uint rarity;
        uint ID;
        string name;
        uint xp;
    }
}

ERC721
import "./library/Helper.sol";
mapping(uint => Helper.TreaninProps) public treaninProps;  
   
...

[IN THE MINT FUNCTION]
_safeMint(to, tokenId);
Helper.TreaninProps storage props = treaninProps[tokenId];
props.summoned = false;

...

The behaviour here is that when an NFT is minted, the treaninProps data structure is assigned to that nft ID.
IERC721
pragma solidity =0.8.20;

import "../library/Helper.sol";

interface IERC721 {
    function treaninProps(uint _nftID) external view returns (Helper.TreaninProps memory);
}

Above is to allow other contracts to query the state of the ERC721 contract. If properties are set for NFT 5 in the ERC721 contract, then Query.sol should be able to read them.
Query
import "./interface/IERC721.sol";
import "./library/Helper.sol";
contract NFTMinter is Initializable, OwnableUpgradeable, UUPSUpgradeable {
    address nftAddress = [ERC721.sol ADDRESS]
    function whyBroken(uint _nftId) external view returns (Helper.TreaninProps memory) {
        Helper.TreaninProps memory props = IERC721(nftAddress).treaninProps(_nftId);
        require(props.summoned, "You have not activated your NFT");
        return(props);
    }
}

Of course, a lot of context is missing here, but above holds all code related to my problem.
When I try to read the "whyBroken" function from Query.sol with an _nftId of "25" (owned but not summoned) this is the output:
call to ERC1967Proxy.whyBroken errored: Error occurred: execution reverted: You have not activated your NFT.

execution reverted: You have not activated your NFT

As expected, the require function prints the error message, as summoned is false.
Now, when I call the same function on _nftId "7" (this ID has been summoned) this is the result:
call to ERC1967Proxy.whyBroken
call to ERC1967Proxy.whyBroken errored: Error occurred: execution reverted.

execution reverted
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
You may want to cautiously increase the gas limit if the transaction went out of gas.

This is not expected. It should be returning all data in "treaninProps". The function is not payable, it's a view function, so gas and payable has nothing to do with it.
When I go to ERC721.sol I am able to query "treaninProps" directly in the contract, getting the state I expected. Why can I not replicate this functionality into the Query.sol contract? What am I misunderstanding?
When I query "treaninProps" directly on the ERC721 contract, with 'id' 7, it returns:
0:
bool: summoned true
1:
uint256: strength 0
2:
uint8: faction 3
3:
uint256: mintTime 1714381220
4:
bool: isFrozen false
5:
uint256: rarity 1
6:
uint256: ID 16
7:
string: name Common Acheron #3
8:
uint256: xp 0

Please can you help explain what is wrong with my contract setup, why data is not being able to be properly used in the Query.sol contract. Whilst in this context provided it is quite mundane, this is causing a critical error in my whole smart contract database, and the error is the exact same. It's indescript and does not tell me why I am unable to use this functionality. I've refined my codebase into this small example above for your sakes, so hopefully you can give me a resolution!
Many thanks.
Edit: If you would like to review the minimum reproducible code, you can find it in this Github repo.

Your code and logic seems to be correctly implemented. Can you share the minimum reproducible version of your full code as a gist, so that I can try debugging the same on my end?

Hi @SYEDASADKAZMI, thank you for your reply. I have created a Github that contains the minimum reproducible code, which you can find here: https://github.com/Blocknite/DebugRevert/tree/master/Contracts

In your current implementation, the treaninProps() function of IERC21 interface that you've created  is just returning the empty struct of type Helper.TreaninProps, and even if it's getting initialised when activate() function is being called, then also it's referencing a different struct due to its presence in Helper library that is used by different contracts, as you can see in the comment of this answer:

even if the structs are the same, they are still considered different
by solidity

That's why, returning the instance of the same when calling whyBroken() function, resulting in the unknown revert.
So, in your Query.sol, instead of importing the ./interface/IERC721.sol, you've to import the ./Treanin.sol, because you're modifying/assigning the treaninProps mapping in the Treanin contract.
Replace this:
i̶m̶p̶o̶r̶t̶ "./i̶n̶t̶e̶r̶f̶a̶c̶e̶/I̶E̶R̶C̶7̶2̶1̶.s̶o̶l̶";̶

With:
import {Treanin} from "./Treanin.sol";

Then, in the whyBroken() function, you can retrieve the mapping element using treaninProps(_nftId) by calling it using Treanin(nftAddress) (i.e., the deployed instance of Treanin contract).
And, finally you can create a new instance of Helper.TreaninProps struct using the corresponding returned values (in the form of tuple) by the mapping.
Here's the revised implementation of whyBroken() function:
function whyBroken(uint256 _nftId)
    external
    view
    returns (Helper.TreaninProps memory)
{
    (
        bool summoned,
        uint256 strength,
        uint256 mintTime,
        bool isFrozen,
        uint256 rarity,
        uint256 ID,
        string memory name,
        uint256 xp
    ) = Treanin(nftAddress).treaninProps(_nftId);

    Helper.TreaninProps memory props = Helper.TreaninProps({
        summoned: summoned,
        strength: strength,
        mintTime: mintTime,
        isFrozen: isFrozen,
        rarity: rarity,
        ID: ID,
        name: name,
        xp: xp
    });

    require(props.summoned, "You have not activated your NFT");
    return (props);
}


Thank you for taking the time to answer my question Syed, this is indeed a rather obscure property of the Solidity compiler. I would unlikely to have been able to understand this without your help :)

You’re welcome, @OpsecOptimum. Happy coding!
